# Setting up OpenStack environment on virtual machines

Tags: virtual-machine, cloud, xen, openstack

I am learning OpenStack for almost a week. After reading most of OpenStack wiki, my mind still blurry at some point. However it is said OpenStack nodes could be installed on virtual machines (VMs) for testing [***](http://docs.openstack.org/juno/install-guide/install/apt/content/ch_basic_environment.html#basics-prerequisites), I couldn't find any running sample whose nodes are installed on VMs.

I wonder how long can I go with nodes on virtual machines? I know sticking to proven architecture with physical nodes will be the best solution but I don't have a budget for buying new servers, new switches, new storage etc.

If I build an environment with nodes on VMs, will I be able to scale my cloud in future? Do I have to make a choice between starting with physical nodes, switches, storage and not starting at all?

Comment: Today I found out a video which also contains my answer. Must watch for newbies. https://youtu.be/pCkzrezRmJI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I couldn't find any running sample whose nodes are installed on VMs.

I'm not sure where you would expect to find a "running sample", but in general, installation on virtual machines is going to be largely identical to installation on physical machines and the upstream documentation at `http://docs.openstack.org/` should get you started.

> I wonder how long can I go with nodes on virtual machines?

There is no single answer to that question.  You will generally find that your compute hosts will perform best when run on physical hardware, but it is not uncommon to run all the other services in virtual environments, even in production deployments.  It really depends on your particular requirements.

> If I build an environment with nodes on VMs, will I be able to scale my cloud in future?

Sure.  OpenStack doesn't care about virtual vs. physical.  You will probably need to make configuration changes as you move from virtual to physical machines (to things like interface names, virtualization type, etc), but there is nothing hardwired about your initial configuration.

Comment: I read docs for sure but Table 1.1 on this page (http://docs.openstack.org/openstack-ops/content/example_architecture.html) confused me. I also couldn't find anyone to say "go with physical or VMs, doesnt't matter". Thank you